# different form field required depending on submit clicked

Tags: php, html

I was wondering if it was possible to make a form field required if I submit my form with one button and not required if I click on another button.

Exemple:

```
<form method="post" action="action.php" name="form1">
<input type="text" name="participant_name" /> //required if submit button = save_button
//not required if submit button = cancel_button

<input type="submit" value="save" name="save_button" />
<input type="submit" value="cancel" name="cancel_button" />
</form>
```

Thx everyone :)

Comment: Do you need the validation in the frondend or backend?

Comment: @Philipp validation is made in the backend

Answer (score 0):

You can add the attribute: required to the input. And make from the cancel button a non submit button with u goback link with javascript.

```
<form method="post" action="action.php" name="form1">
<input type="text" name="participant_name" required/>

<input type="submit" value="save" name="save_button" />
<input type="button" value="cancel" onclick="window.history.back();"/>
```

Otherwise you should write a javascript/jquery script that validates the form after form submit.

Here is running code: https://jsfiddle.net/zmm896n2/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I put cancel as a simple link instead of a submit button but I was still wondering is it was possible. Anyway it sounds like the answer to each and every one of my questions is "JS can do it". I guess I know what's the next language I'll learn :D

Comment: Ye better start learning JS right away. And start learning jQuery also. That saves you a lot of work and time later on.